# crm 2011: change IIS authencation to basic authencation only

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

After I change authentication for Crm portal to basic authentication only?
(Enabling Basic Authentication and Disabling Windows Authentication in IIS),
the Organization Service Endpoint no longer works.

then I found the following error message in windows event log.

The service '/Org/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Basic') do not allow those configured on the binding 'CustomBinding' ('Anonymous').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly.  Additionally, this may be resolved by changing the authentication schemes for this application through the IIS management tool, through the ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the application configuration file at the  element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding, or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the HttpTransportBindingElement.. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Basic') do not allow those configured on the binding 'CustomBinding' ('Anonymous').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly.  Additionally, this may be resolved by changing the authentication schemes for this application through the IIS management tool, through the ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the application configuration file at the  element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding, or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the HttpTransportBindingElement.

Is it possible to enable basic authentication only for crm?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: Because such kind of modifications are called unsupported, not recommended with Microsoft and not tested for usage.